# Method chaining solution to drop column level in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, method-chaining

I am using lot's of method chaining when reshaping and querying data I have in pandas `DataFrames`. Sometimes additional and unnecessary levels for the in indices (rows) and columns are being created. If so, e.g. on the the index (row-axis) this is easily solved by using `DataFrame.reset_index()`:

```
df.query('some query')
   .apply(cool_func)
   .reset_index('unwanted_index_level',drop=True) # <====
   .apply(another_cool_func)
```

The `reset_index` function allows one to continue chain methods and keep working with the `DataFrame`.

Nevertheless, I never found an equivalent solution for the column_axis. Is there any at all?

Comment: Are you looking for the `.drop` to drop a column?

Comment: Hi - No I want to drop a level from the `MultiIndex` in the axis `DataFrame.columns`

Comment: How do you want to handle the duplication of column names that occurs if a column index level is removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just `stack` the column (move it to the index) and call `reset_index` with drop=True, or you could write a `reset_columns()` method using the `reset_index()` one as a starting point (see frame.py#L2940)

```
df.query('some query')
   .apply(cool_func)
   .stack(level='unwanted_col_level_name')
   .reset_index('unwanted_col_level_name',drop=True)
   .apply(another_cool_func)
```

---

Alternative: Monkey patch solution

```
def drop_column_levels(self, level=None, inplace=False):
        """
        For DataFrame with multi-level columns, drops one or more levels.
        For a standard index, or if dropping all levels of the MultiIndex, will revert
        back to using a classic RangeIndexer for column names.

        Parameters
        ----------
        level : int, str, tuple, or list, default None
            Only remove the given levels from the index. Removes all levels by
            default
        inplace : boolean, default False
            Modify the DataFrame in place (do not create a new object)

        Returns
        -------
        resetted : DataFrame
        """
        if inplace:
            new_obj = self
        else:
            new_obj = self.copy()

        new_columns = pd.core.common._default_index(len(new_obj.columns))
        if isinstance(self.index, pd.MultiIndex):
            if level is not None:
                if not isinstance(level, (tuple, list)):
                    level = [level]
                level = [self.index._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level]
                if len(level) < len(self.columns.levels):
                    new_columns = self.columns.droplevel(level)

        new_obj.columns = new_columns
        if not inplace:
            return new_obj

# Monkey patch the DataFrame class
pd.DataFrame.drop_column_levels = drop_column_levels
```

Comment: Great! I was not aware of the `stack` function! It may come in handy also for other things! It works nicely

Answer (score 3):

I just found another solution myself, which is using the `.T` field of the `DataFrame` which equivalent to `DataFrame.transpose()`.

```
df.query('some query')
   .apply(cool_func)
   .T.reset_index('unwanted_col_level_name',drop=True).T
   .apply(another_cool_func)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option to allowed continued dot-chaining is to define a new method for the `pd.DataFrame` class that reduces the column index level.  This is called monkey patching, and it reduces the portability of your code.

```
def reset_column_index(self, inplace=False):
    if inplace:
        self.columns = ['_'.join(tup) for tup in self.columns]
    else:
        c = self.copy()
        c.columns = ['_'.join(tup) for tup in c.columns]
        return c

pd.DataFrame.reset_column_index = reset_column_index

df.query('some query')
   .apply(cool_func)
   .reset_column_index()
   .apply(another_cool_func)
```

Using this method will flatten a multi-index column to a single index, merging the names with underscores.

```
#     foo          bar
#       A     B      A     B
# 0    17     2      0     3
# 1     4    12     40    11
```

becomes

```
#   foo_A   foo_B   bar_A   bar_B
# 0    17       2       0       3
# 1     4      12      40      11
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think it is valid - but I tend to choose options which are already 'packaged' in order for compatibility and not always to have to define the same functions

Comment: I completely agree.  @Julien's answer seems to work well.